# Matlab - load results from parallel job that has not finished yet

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Is there a way to retrieve the variables of a batch job that has not finished yet?
If not, how do I perform some kind of checkpointing, so I could retrieve intermediate results from a parallel job?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there a few things you can do. First, something like this to see if your job is done:

```
while ~strcmp(jobHandle.State, 'Finished')
    jobHandle.Task
    jobHandle.Task(1)
    jobHandle.Task(1).State
    jobHandle.Task(1).OutputArguments
end
```

Inside that loop, you'll have access to the job object, and all the task objects for that job. I tried to demo some of the data you have access to in the impractical example above. You can use that data-access to set up any checkpoint scheme you want. See the documentation, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/fetchoutputs.html), for more info. Good Luck!